# Поиск как в браузерах

Tags: sql, postgresql

Суть проблемы в том, что нужно по названию найти все похожие элементы в таблице. Тоесть у меня есть таблица news и в ней есть поле title. Так вот нужно допустим чтобы искались все новости, где title похожий допустим на "Transport", или допустим даже если в слове есть ошибка "ransport" все-равно находило нужное.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch.html

Comment: а можно пример sql запроса?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title FROM news
WHERE to_tsvector(body) @@ to_tsquery('ransport');
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-SEARCH

```
SELECT title FROM news
WHERE title LIKE '%ransport'
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать еще по похожим словам поиск, ну к примеру, если ошибку в слове допустил, но оно все-равно нашло то, что имел ввиду?